# forms and javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form button and I want 2 lines of text.  In the form I have this

```
value='".$row['item'].'&#10;$'.$row['price']."'
```

and I get

```
Hot Dog
$1.00
```

I want to update this in JavaScript and tried this

```
sBtn = itm + "&#10;$" + prc;
document.getElementById(conbtn).value = sBtn;
```

and

```
sBtn = itm + "<br>$" + prc;
document.getElementById(conbtn).value = sBtn;
```

without success.  The first gives

```
Hot Dog&#10;$1.00
```

and the second

```
Hot Dog<br>$1.00
```

Any idea how to write 2 lines from JS?

Comment: try using innerHtml instead of value

Comment: What is `conbtn`? Is it `<input type='button'>`?

Comment: Set the innerHTML property of the conbtn element to sBtn instead of its value property to sBtn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  Used

```
sBtn = itm + "\r\n$" + prc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a form input button, use an escaped newline in the `value` property.

```
document.getElementById(conbtn).value = "Test 1\nTest 2";
```

If you have a button tag element, use a break element in the `innerHTML` property.

```
document.getElementById(conbtn).innerHTML = "Test 1<br/>Test 2";
```